# Is Relative URLs unfunctional on sites hosted on github?

Tags: html, css, github

I have hosted [my site](https://dinataklit.github.io/Dina-Taklit-Portfilio/) on github. I have used a **background-image url** using a **relative path**

```
/assets/Images/
```

This work just fine on my local workspace but on git it does not work :(.  I wonder why?

Does relative paths does not work on Git?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative paths on web pages can be a bit confusing.

If you have a web server on https://www.example.com, you may be serving those pages from `/var/www/html` but the browser only sees it as `/`.

So if you have a link, image, etc, that refers to `/assets/Images/background.jpg`, it goes to the server and says, "I'd like resource at https://www.example.com/assets/Images/background.jpg".

The web server then looks up where that file is on the server.  Keeping with our example, it would be located on `/var/www/html/assets/Images/background.jpg`.

In your website, your URL is `https://dinataklit.github.io/Dina-Taklit-Portfilio/`.  This means if you are using an image `/assets/Images/background.jpg`, it will ask the server "I would like the resource at https://dinataklit.github.io/assets/Images/background.jpg"

You can fix this in one of two ways:

- [Set `<base href="https://dinataklit.github.io/Dina-Taklit-Portfilio/">`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp).  Doing this may break your local view
- Set your resources to be relative to it's current directory by prepending with `./`, e.g. `./assets/Images/background.jpg`.  This should work both locally as well as on github, but you have to do it to each item you are referencing.

A good way to test this is to create a link on your page, one with `/` and one with `./`:

```
<a href="/">I wonder where this goes</a><br/>
<a href="./">I wonder where THIS goes</a><br/>
```

Then mouse hover over each link and see how the browser resolves each link.  The first link will most likely take you to https://dinataklit.github.io/ whereas the second will go to https://dinataklit.github.io/Dina-Taklit-Portfilio/

Comment: Though the `./assets` does not work locally hhh. It really confusing like you have said.

Comment: Hmm... `./assets` should work locally.  Can you create a link and see how the browser is resolving it?  Also, how are you testing it locally?  Do you have a full web server stack (e.g. apache/nginx) or are you viewing the HTML file through the browser?

Comment: I used live server on Visual Code. This is the local linl `http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html`

Comment: If `index.html` sits in the root of the directory, `./assets` should resolve to the assets subdirectory.  When you create the link to `<a href="./assets">Link</a>`, what address does it take you to?

Comment: It's highly possible that Visual Code may have a setting that says "/Assets are served somewhere else."  I would try viewing the page directly using your web browser's open function and seeing if it works.

Comment: It leads to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/.` The `./` does not work on background image url : `#header::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('./assets/Images/header.svg');...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203541/discussion-between-scuba-mike-and-dina-taklit).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the url to this

```
url('../../assets/Images/header.svg');
```

Because you are using a relative path you will need to go back directories using `../`

Comment: why can we just use jus  /assets. I wanna understand why.

Comment: Because of the directory structure of your site. Your index.html is not located within the same directory as the assets folder but is inside another. So you will have to go back out of that directory and into the assets folder

Comment: Another question please Once i have removed the forward slash on js writing assets/Images.. it worked fine on the project section. But on the header no. What could be this mystery?